# Why pandas multiindex dataframe level is sometimes dropped when indexing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm experimenting with multiindex dataframe.  I'm learning from: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers

I have some trouble understanding the rule for pandas to sometimes automatically drop level when indexing.  Hopefully the following code will help better explain my question:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Utility function to quickly create label array
def mklbl(prefix, n):
    return ["%s%d" % (prefix, i) for i in range(n)]

# Create multiindex row & columns:
miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [mklbl('A', 2), mklbl('B', 2), mklbl('C', 3)],
    names=['IdxLvl0', 'IdxLvl1', 'IdxLvl2']
)
micolumns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [mklbl('X', 2), mklbl('Y', 2), mklbl('Z', 3)],
    names=["ColLvl0", "ColLvl1", "ColLvl2"]
)
# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
        np.arange(len(miindex) * len(micolumns)).reshape(
            (len(miindex), len(micolumns))
        ),
        index=miindex,
        columns=micolumns,
    )
# Original:
print(df)
```

Original df:

```
ColLvl0                   X0                            X1                         
ColLvl1                   Y0             Y1             Y0             Y1          
ColLvl2                   Z0   Z1   Z2   Z0   Z1   Z2   Z0   Z1   Z2   Z0   Z1   Z2
IdxLvl0 IdxLvl1 IdxLvl2                                                            
A0      B0      C0         0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
                C1        12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23
                C2        24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35
        B1      C0        36   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47
                C1        48   49   50   51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59
                C2        60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71
A1      B0      C0        72   73   74   75   76   77   78   79   80   81   82   83
                C1        84   85   86   87   88   89   90   91   92   93   94   95
                C2        96   97   98   99  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  107
        B1      C0       108  109  110  111  112  113  114  115  116  117  118  119
                C1       120  121  122  123  124  125  126  127  128  129  130  131
                C2       132  133  134  135  136  137  138  139  140  141  142  143
```

When indexing by row or columns, depending on the method, the level is sometimes dropped.

```py
# Index: IdxLvl0 is dropped:
df.loc['A0']
```

```
ColLvl0          X0                      X1                    
ColLvl1          Y0          Y1          Y0          Y1        
ColLvl2          Z0  Z1  Z2  Z0  Z1  Z2  Z0  Z1  Z2  Z0  Z1  Z2
IdxLvl1 IdxLvl2                                                
B0      C0        0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
        C1       12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
        C2       24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35
B1      C0       36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47
        C1       48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
        C2       60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71
```

```py
# Shortcut for indexer:
idx = pd.IndexSlice

# Index: IdxLvl0 is NOT dropped:
df.loc[idx['A0', :, :]]
```

```
ColLvl0                  X0                      X1                    
ColLvl1                  Y0          Y1          Y0          Y1        
ColLvl2                  Z0  Z1  Z2  Z0  Z1  Z2  Z0  Z1  Z2  Z0  Z1  Z2
IdxLvl0 IdxLvl1 IdxLvl2                                                
A0      B0      C0        0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
                C1       12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
                C2       24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35
        B1      C0       36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47
                C1       48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
                C2       60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71
```

```py
# Index: IdxLvl2 is dropped:
df.loc[idx[:, :, 'C2']]
```

```
ColLvl0           X0                            X1                         
ColLvl1           Y0             Y1             Y0             Y1          
ColLvl2           Z0   Z1   Z2   Z0   Z1   Z2   Z0   Z1   Z2   Z0   Z1   Z2
IdxLvl0 IdxLvl1                                                            
A0      B0        24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35
        B1        60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71
A1      B0        96   97   98   99  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  107
        B1       132  133  134  135  136  137  138  139  140  141  142  143
```

```py
# Index: IdxLvl2 is NOT dropped:
df.loc[idx[:, :, 'C2'], :]
```

```
ColLvl0                   X0                            X1                         
ColLvl1                   Y0             Y1             Y0             Y1          
ColLvl2                   Z0   Z1   Z2   Z0   Z1   Z2   Z0   Z1   Z2   Z0   Z1   Z2
IdxLvl0 IdxLvl1 IdxLvl2                                                            
A0      B0      C2        24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35
        B1      C2        60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71
A1      B0      C2        96   97   98   99  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  107
        B1      C2       132  133  134  135  136  137  138  139  140  141  142  143
```

Similar differences occur also for column (omitting all outputs for brevity):

```py
# ColLvl0 dropped
df.loc[idx['A0', :, 'C2'], idx['X0']]

# ColLvl0 NOT dropped
df.loc[idx['A0', :, 'C2'], idx['X0', :, :]]

# ColLvl1 NOT dropped
df.loc[idx['A0', :, 'C2'], idx[:, 'Y1']]

# ColLvl2 NOT dropped
df.loc[idx['A0', :, 'C2'], idx[:, :, 'Z2']]
```

Any pointers on this behavior would be greatly appreciated.

Also, any suggestions on how to "automatically" drop any index/column level not required, ie: when the values are the same.

If it helps, I'm using pandas 1.1.5

Thanks!